# Unable to completely download OSM file to PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I used this command to import the osm file to PostGIS:

`osm2pgsql /Desktop/osm/mtl.osm -d demo_data -U blanco -P 5432 -S "/usr/local/share/osm2pgsql/default.style" --hstore`

I am using osm2pgsql SVN version 0.84.0 (64bit id space)

Why am I unable to download `planet_osm_nodes`?

```
Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_line_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_roads_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Using built-in tag processing pipeline
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=800MB, maxblocks=102400*8192, allocation method=3
Mid: Ram, scale=100

Reading in file: /Users/hadoop/Desktop/osm/mtl.osm
StartElement: Unknown element name: note
Unknown node type 3
EndElement: Unknown element name: note
StartElement: Unknown element name: meta
EndElement: Unknown element name: meta.   
Processing: Node(1234k 112.2k/s) Way(248k 15.56k/s) Relation(6805 3402.50/s)        parse time: 29s

Node stats: total(1234539), max(4764987639) in 11s
Way stats: total(248884), max(483754469) in 16s
Relation stats: total(6805), max(7120865) in 2s
Committing transaction for planet_osm_point
Committing transaction for planet_osm_line
Committing transaction for planet_osm_polygon
Committing transaction for planet_osm_roads

Writing way (248k)
Committing transaction for planet_osm_point
Committing transaction for planet_osm_line
Committing transaction for planet_osm_polygon
Committing transaction for planet_osm_roads

Writing relation (6798)
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_point
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_line
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_polygon
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_roads
node cache: stored: 1234539(100.00%), storage efficiency: 52.39% (dense    blocks: 276, sparse nodes: 1036935), hit rate: 98.58%
Analyzing planet_osm_roads finished
Copying planet_osm_roads to cluster by geometry finished
Creating geometry index on  planet_osm_roads
Creating indexes on  planet_osm_roads finished
All indexes on  planet_osm_roads created  in 1s
Completed planet_osm_roads
Analyzing planet_osm_polygon finished
Analyzing planet_osm_line finished
Analyzing planet_osm_point finished
Copying planet_osm_polygon to cluster by geometry finished
Creating geometry index on  planet_osm_polygon
Copying planet_osm_line to cluster by geometry finished
Creating geometry index on  planet_osm_line
Copying planet_osm_point to cluster by geometry finished
Creating geometry index on  planet_osm_point
Creating indexes on  planet_osm_polygon finished
All indexes on  planet_osm_polygon created  in 5s
Completed planet_osm_polygon
Creating indexes on  planet_osm_line finished
All indexes on  planet_osm_line created  in 7s
Completed planet_osm_line
Creating indexes on  planet_osm_point finished
All indexes on  planet_osm_point created  in 8s
Completed planet_osm_point

Osm2pgsql took 54s overall
```

Comment: Are you worried about the `note` and `meta` parts?

Comment: I'm new in OSM, I'm using Python 'osmapi' and I would like to extract amenity from nodes, thats why I'm looking for planet_osm_nodes table to use osmapi.OsmApi().NodeGet(123). I'm not worried about note and meta parts. I only need to use the planet_osm_nodes table. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

osmapi is intended to work against the http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6 which probably isn't what you want - that is the editing API.

Maybe you would be better off looking at the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) which you can use off a public instance, or [install your own](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/install) if your needs exceed the public usage limits.

Comment: ...or a pre-made extract as provided at http://download.geofabrik.de/ and similar services.